# jquery alert says undefined

Tags: jquery, alert

Hi, I'm trying to get the alert method to show the value c8 but it just says undefined.

I'm new to html and jquery; it's simple but I just can't see it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
      //$("#div1").load("hs.php");
      //$("#div1").load("http://127.0.0.1:81/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&f=DeviceStatus&d=A1");
        $("#div1").load("http://127.0.0.1:81/tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&f=ToggleDevice&d=c8");
        alert($(this).prev().attr(".class"));
       });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
    <span class='c8'><button>Get External Content</button></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you put this in jsfiddle? Also, I believe that it's supposed to be attr("class") with no "." (period)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy initially I thought that was the issue too but it's just the terrible indentation. There is no `.load()` callback here.

Comment: @Matt Ball Good catch. I'll see myself out.

Answer (score 1):

Because prev() is for sibblings only. your button is child of that div.

You should go:

```
alert($(this).parent().attr("class"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The button has no siblings `.prev()` is used to select the previous sibling, the element you want to target is its parent therefore use `.parent()` to select it. Also you only prepend the class with a dot (`.`) when it is part of a selector.

```
alert($(this).parent().attr("class"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the dot before attribute names:

```
alert($(this).prev().attr("class"));
```

Answer (score 0):

While in jQuery the `.` introduces a *class selector*, in this case you just want an attribute called "class".

Remove the `.` in `.class`:

```
alert($(this).prev().attr("class"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.attr("class")` instead (without the `.`)