# 'alert' undefined in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xhtml, alert

I am trying to make a field in a php form required. I am using Dreamweaver Cs3.

Dreamweaver generated the following function

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_validateForm() { //v4.0
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var i, p, q, nm, test, num, min, max, errors = '',
            args = MM_validateForm.arguments;
        for (i = 0; i < (args.length - 2); i += 3) {
            test = args[i + 2];
            val = document.getElementById(args[i]);
            if (val) {
                nm = val.name;
                if ((val = val.value) != "") {
                    if (test.indexOf('isEmail') != -1) {
                        p = val.indexOf('@');
                        if (p < 1 || p == (val.length - 1)) errors += '- ' + nm + ' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
                    } else if (test != 'R') {
                        num = parseFloat(val);
                        if (isNaN(val)) errors += '- ' + nm + ' must contain a number.\n';
                        if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) {
                            p = test.indexOf(':');
                            min = test.substring(8, p);
                            max = test.substring(p + 1);
                            if (num < min || max < num) errors += '- ' + nm + ' must contain a number between ' + min + ' and ' + max + '.\n';
                        }
                    }
                } else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- ' + nm + ' is required.\n';
            }
        }
        if (errors) alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n' + errors);

        document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
    }
}
//-->
  </script>
```

and called it in the

```
<form action="registered.php" method="post" name="frmRegister" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('addr1','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" >
```

When I run it on a chrome browser, I get an error saying alert is undefined.

I tried checking other answers but I am unable to get the code working. Could someone please help?

Other answers:

[Injecting JS functions into the page from a Greasemonkey script on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303147/injecting-js-functions-into-the-page-from-a-greasemonkey-script-on-chrome)

[jquery alert says undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167838/jquery-alert-says-undefined)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp

Comment: Thanks all. I found out the solution. from the page 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184169/alert-not-working-in-chrome?rq=1

Adding the following before alert resolved the issue

delete window.alert; // true

An explanation ahs been posted by Matty F for that question

Comment: @Lopez please answer the question yourself, or close it, so that it is no longer listed as "unanswered".

Comment: Answer is here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184169/alert-not-working-in-chrome?rq=1